# Hide activity indicator when uiwebview loads

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a uiwebview in a custom table cell. I am trying to get my activity indicator to disappear when the uiwebview is loaded. Currently it is just appearing but not disappearing.

I know I need to link up the delegate but found it slightly more complicated as it is a custom table cell. I linked up the UIWebView delegate.

So in `videoCell.h` my `UITableViewCell` i have :

```
@interface videoCell : UITableViewCell <UIWebViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webViewVideo;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *indicatorSpinner;

@end
```

followed by the following in the `videoCell.m` file.

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{ [indicatorSpinner startAnimating];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{ [indicatorSpinner stopAnimating];
    indicatorSpinner.hidden = TRUE;
}
```

In my `UITableViewController`

```
if( indexPath.row == 0 ) {
    videoCell *cell = nil;
    cell = (videoCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:videoCellIdentfier];
    if( !cell ) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"videoViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    UIWebView* webView = (UIWebView*)[cell viewWithTag:1001];

    //https://youtube.googleapis.com/v/6eK-W32IME0

    NSString *html = @"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/CAGBKxvBkxI?fs=1&hl=en_US&enablejsapi=1\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"320\" height=\"200\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";

    [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    return cell;
```

Comment: if you haven't changed a default value for `hidesWhenStopped` in indicatorSpinner property you do not need to call this `indicatorSpinner.hidden = TRUE;`

Comment: @viperking that doesnt fix the issue;

Comment: Have you debugged it if it goes in webViewDidFinishLoad?

Comment: Were you able to set the `UITableViewCell` object as the web view's `UIWebViewDelegate`? Can you show us how?

Comment: I know that it is not the fix this is why I made it as a comment because you do not really need this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialise the cell you should add:

```
webViewVideo.delegate = self;
```

Alternatively you can do it directly in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking to see if the activity indicator is spinning first in webViewDidFinishLoad: method.

```
if ([indicatorSpinner isSpinning]){

          [indicatorSpinner stopAnimating];


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make 
[indicatorSpinner stopAnimating];
[indicatorSpinner setHidden:true];